# How to select from / join 5 tables using PHP and mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, join, distinct

I'm trying to build a review record based on fields from 5 tables:

[image]

I've marked all the columns I need, but for the moment I'm just retrieving all of the user_rating table.

Here's what I have so far:

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_rating.*, whiskey.name, user_notes.overall, users.image, user_rate.rate_number
    FROM user_rating
    LEFT JOIN whiskey ON whiskey.id = user_rating.whiskeyid
    LEFT JOIN users ON users.username = user_rating.username
    LEFT JOIN user_notes ON user_notes.username = user_rating.username AND user_rating.whiskeyid = user_notes.whiskey_id
    LEFT JOIN user_rate ON user_rate.whiskey_id = user_rating.whiskeyid AND user_rate.username = user_rating.username
    ORDER BY user_rating.id DESC
```

At first I thought this was giving me the results I wanted but then I noticed I was getting multiple rows as well as too many null fields. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:

By multiple rows I mean duplicate rows. Also, I am aware that a left join produces null values on the right side of the join. What I meant to say is that I'm getting more null values than I should be as the data is within the database.

To clarify, I'm trying to create a list of recent reviews with the most recent listed first. Each review consists of a username, 11 categories (each one is an integer value), overall rating (int value), notes (string), image (URL), and whiskey name (string).

Comment: A left join says "give me all the records on the left side even if there isn't a matching record on the table I'm joining". The net result of left and right joins is usually NULL fields for the corresponding tables. If you want only the cases where the join condition is true, change the "LEFT" to "INNER".

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and an example of what you *do* want?

Comment: @GordonLinoff The picture I posted shows the structure of the tables I'm querying. I edited my post to clarify what I need in the results. I'll put some sample data together to further clarify.

Comment: @Bishop Can you post a few of the duplicate records you are getting? Based on the query I'm not sure why you would be getting them and based on the structure and your query it's not immediately evident.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that there was nothing wrong with my query. The person whose database I'm using isn't maintaining it so there are several reviews for the same product and user where only the overall rating is different. Also, there are many reviews on products that don't even exist. I should've looked at the database closer to begin with as deleting all of the erroneous rows solved my problem. Thanks for all the input.

Answer (score 0):

1) You can't be getting multiple SAME rows, since you use DISTINCT. (by multiple do you mean duplicate?)

2) You get null fields because you are using LEFT JOIN and your tables cannot be joined (some "ON clause" cannot be evaluated as true)

Comment: 1) That's what I understood the DISTINCT clause to accomplish, but yes, I mean duplicate rows. 2) I understand that a left join inherently creates nulls fields, however the results given by my query contain too many null entries based on the data within the database.

Comment: It sounds odd. This shouldn't happen. Could you provide some data? maybe use something like sqlfiddle?